# error for cvtColor method opencv-python image processing for edge detection

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

This is the code I got online and it's throwing errors

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img0, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img0, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
error: ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:3737: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cv::cvtColor
```

I want to perform edge detection but half the way when I am trying to convert the image from rgb to gray scale its throwing error. Why is it pointing to cpp program in opencv folder when I have written code in python ?

Comment: it tells you that img0 isnt rgb because it doesnt have 3 (or 4) channels... can you try to print img0.channels to find out what it really is?

Comment: @Micka you mean img0.shape

Comment: possible, I don't know much about python/numpy API :D